# filter a sorted array in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, sorting, apache-spark

What is the most efficient way to filter a sorted array in scala/spark.

Below is the code sample to sort and filter

```
  val sortQueueByDate = udf { (rows: WrappedArray[Row]) =>
  rows
    .map { case Row(i: String, s: String) => (i, s) }
    .sortBy(_._1)
}

val filterQueueByDateRange = udf {
  (rows: WrappedArray[Row], startDate: String, endDate: String) =>
    rows
      .map { case Row(i: String, s: String) => (i, s) }
      .filter(
        row => row._1.>(startDate) && row._1.<(endDate)
      )
}
```

Output from sortQueueByDate  function.

[[**20161216**, 20161216~10490087146611006160~l6vHAXv~0.3333~180.0],

[**20170628**, 20170628~100~bay~0.3333333333333333~180.0],

[**20180206**, 20180206~104901yyy10325056~l6vHAXv~0.3333~180.0],

[**20180806**, 20180806~100~89iuh~0.3333333333333333~180.0],

[**20190214**, 20190214~10490162xxx5734~hatu~0.3333~180.0]]

when we apply filter function on above items it scans all the items and is in-efficient.

Can someone suggest an better option.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would filter in DataFRame API, not in UDF. If you must, you could use something like `takeWhile` which will stop the first time the condition is not satisfied, thus preventing to traverse the entire Seq:

```
  rows
      .takeWhile{row => row.getString(0)>startDate && row.getString(0)<endDate}
      .map { case Row(i: String, s: String) => (i, s) }
```

Important : `map` after `takeWhile`, otherwise you will traverse the entire Seq (you can use lazy collections like `View`/`Stream` to overcome this.

Comment: But will it perform the required functionality , if it stops on first execution. The statement may be true after n iterations.